# I want to print 1 to 10 counting in a text file using php

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops

I'm trying to get 1 to 10 counting in a file using PHP loops but that does not work how can I fix this code

I'm running PHP 7+ and I tried to use for loop and they then used the increment variable  in foreach loop still didn't work

```
<?php

    for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {

        $fp = fopen('lidn.txt', 'w');

    $a = [$i];
    foreach ($a as $value) {
        fwrite($fp ,$i);


        echo "$value";

    fclose($fp);

}
}

?>
```

I expected the output would be 012345678910 on the text file 
but what I get is only 10

Answer (score 1):

Each time you open the file you place the cursor at the beginning of the file, and then overwrite it with subsequent `fwrite` calls.

For a task like this, you should only open the file one, perform all the writes, and then close it:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('lidn.txt', 'w');
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        fwrite($fp, $i);
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_put_contents` with `range` and `implode` instead of looping

```
file_put_contents('lidn.txt', implode('',range(0,10)));
```